# I wanted to extract the all the orderNumber values from given xml response in Jmeter

Tags: regex, xml, jmeter, cdata

I wanted to extract the all the orderNumber values from given XML response in JMeter

Regular Expression I am using : `orderNumber=(".*?")`

**Xml:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ReportExecuted ReportId="4130" >
           <DisplayName>Partner Asset - Landing Page (No Glis Orders) Descending</DisplayName>
           <ExecutedBy>admin</ExecutedBy>
           <ExecutionTime>Thu Nov 16 07:32:29 UTC 2017</ExecutionTime>
           <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
           <PageSize>10</PageSize>
           <DisplayRecords>1 to 10</DisplayRecords>
           <TotalRecords>1000</TotalRecords>
           <ReportContent>
                          <![CDATA[
    <partnerAssetLandingPage orderNumber="AutoSoapEONID11486" orderDate="2017-07-20T00:00:00"/><partnerAssetLandingPage orderNumber="AutoOrder101" orderDate="2016-11-04T00:00:00"/>

                          ]]>
              </ReportContent>
           </ReportExecuted>
```

**Response after running Jmeter:**
I am only getting the 1st order Number value but I want all the order No values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is ok, you should update `Match No.` to -1 (or negative number) and then [get all the values](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor_parms1) by reference name for example for orderNumber - use orderNumber_1, orderNumber_2,...

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed. The variables are set as follows:
>
> refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0
>   refName_n, where n = 1, 2, 3 etc. - the strings as generated by the template
>   refName_n_gm, where m=0, 1, 2 - the groups for match n
>   refName - always set to the default value
>   refName_gn - not set
>   Note that the refName variable is always set to the default value in this case, and the associated group variables are not set.

You can work with [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

> It is especially suited for running with the regular expression post-processor. 
> This can "create" the necessary input variables out of the result data of a previous request. By omitting the "_" separator, the ForEach Controller can be used to loop through the groups by using the input variable refName_g, and can also loop through all the groups in all the matches by using an input variable of the form refName_${C}_g, where C is a counter variable.